# How do I remove \n when making a list from csv?

Tags: python

All I'm trying to do is make a list of attributes without newline `\n` at the end of each record.

```
import os, csv

output = os.system('hive -S -e "use precache; select geode from database WHERE geodetype = 17;" > testausnzl.csv')


f = open('testausnzl.txt').read()

print f 

ausnzl_list = open("testausnzl.csv").readlines()
```

Comment: it's `\n`, and use [strip](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fstdtypes.html&ei=xKXOU-rOH-X34QSyiIHQDg&usg=AFQjCNHFI1L1yvOml6e4sBQy7gfW3X0cdg&sig2=O2tMB6psQFJXAAiNOf388g&bvm=bv.71198958,d.bGE)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the `csv` module to do the reading:

```
with open("testausnzl.csv", 'rb') as f:
    ausnzl_list = list(csv.reader(f))
```

This will remove the newline characters and produce rows (split on commas).

Instead of a temporary filename, you could use have Python read from the command directly:

```
import csv
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['hive', '-S', '-e', 
     '"use precache; select geode from database WHERE geodetype = 17;"'],
    buffer=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
reader = csv.reader(process.stdout)
for row in reader:
    # process each row as you receive it
```

Instead of loading everything into a list, here the code just loops over the `csv.reader()` object, to process each row as it comes in instead. That is usually the better and more memory efficient approach.

The best approach would be to use a [Python client to connect to hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-Python) and not use the command line client at all.